# How can I trigger a keydown event from code in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, events, keyboard, keydown

I tried to put down a shape of Tetris with setInterval, and I had a function implemented that with keydown pressed, if it can, the shape will bi down 1 block, but I want do that every second... So, how can I trigger a keydown event in code to reuse my function?

Thanks and sorry for my english!

Arkaitz

Comment: Show us some bit of code of what you have tried that failed to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some thing like this should work.

```
    var newEvent = $.Event('keydown', {
        keyCode: event.keyCode
    });
    newEvent.keyCode = $.ui.keyCode.DOWN;
    $(this).trigger(newEvent);
```